# How to read greek input from keyboard using the Scanner class?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8

Im studying java for some time now and i have just encountered this problem.
When i try to read Greek letters with the scanner class,just everything goes wrong.

Example
--in the main method

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
```

--in console i type for example

```
->Ελλάδα
```

i get as a result:������

Im using netbeans IDE.

Am i doing something wrong?Scanner support greek letters?Any alternative solution to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just found the solution to my problem.As it seems the default encoding of netbeans wasnt utf-8 so i edited the netbeans installation/etc/netbeans.conf file.
In the line starting with:netbeans_default_options i added to the end of the string this:-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 so now it looks like this

---

netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"

---

Comment: Thanks for sharing ! Spent a whole night trying to figure out what was happening with Netbeans!! The same issue is still happening when using javac via cmd but with intelij worked out of the box !

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Scanner default encoding to UTF8.  This will allow you to display Greek characters correctly:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Answer {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in, "utf-8");
        System.out.println("enter greek letters");
        String myStr = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println(myStr);
    }
}
```

Another thing to try is to make sure that NetBeans has the correct (UTF-8) encoding set "for the NetBeans application".  Have a look at: https://www.muehlencord.de/wordpress/2015/10/16/netbeans-utf8-encoding/

This tells you how to Set "UTF-8 encoding on Netbeans".

Comment: Im getting the same result :/